# dereferencing nested hash perl

Tags: perl, perl-hash

If I declare a hash like this:

```
my %n = (a => {1 => "1a",2 => "2a"},"b" => {1 => "1b",2 => "2b"});
```

How do I access the data in:  n -> a -> 1?

I tried

```
print "$n{a{1}}";

print "$n{a ->{ 1}}";
```

These two don't work

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Access-and-Printing-of-a-HASH-OF-HASHES)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %n = (a => {1 => "1a",2 => "2a"},"b" => {1 => "1b",2 => "2b"});
print "$n{a}{1}\n";

__END__

1a
```

Comment: Which is short for `$n{a}->{1}`.